# How to get the blocked list on Android?

Tags: android, permissions, contacts

I know the Api27 has a official ContentProvider exposing the Blocked numbers, but only the Sys default sms app can access it. Is there any way for common app to get the block contacts?

Answer (score 0):

according to [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BlockedNumberContract)

For get list of blocking numbers

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(BlockedNumbers.CONTENT_URI,
      new String[]{BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_ID, BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_ORIGINAL_NUMBER,
      BlockedNumbers.COLUMN_E164_NUMBER}, null, null, null);
```

This Cursor contain list of blocking number

Comment: but it also said that **Only** the system, the default SMS application, and the default phone app (See TelecomManager.getDefaultDialerPackage()), and carrier apps (See CarrierService) can read, and write to the blockednumber provider.